# String Array And a String Parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-mobile-5.0

I"m developing a simple application that have a line like this:

```
string[] values = ReadAll(inputFile);
```

As inputFile is a string, but how I can do this without conflicts(Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' in 'string[]')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `ReadAll` method has a signature like this

```
string ReadAll(string inputFile);
```

then the problem is not with `inputFile` but with the return value of the method which cannot be assigned to a `string[]`.

---

Are you maybe looking for [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)?

```
string[] values = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
```

Or do you want to [split a string by some delimeter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)?

```
string[] values = ReadAll(inputFile).Split('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks, the second snippet is what I'm needing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception message you gave us, `ReadAll(inputFile)` returns a `string`, and you assign it to a `string[]`, so that's why it doesn't work.

This would work:

```
string input = ReadAll(inputFile);
```

After this do you want to split the strings in some way? We'd need more details to help you further.